# UIWebView third party website with custom stylesheet

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

How can I add custom local stylesheet to UIWebView which is requested a third party website such as facebook.com.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let URL = NSURL(string: "www.any3rdpartywebsite.com" )
        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: in wkWebview you can inject script by using WKUserScript. But for UIWebView, you might have to inject via javascript I think.